# Java code for Restricted Boltzmann machines and Deep Learning

Tags: java, machine-learning, neural-network, rbm

Since last few days I am reading and studying about Restricted Boltzmann machines and Deep Learning. Now to test the ability of Deep learning I am in search of Java code.
I searched for long time on Google but could not get any satisfactory implementation.

As an example, I found following java library for Restricted Boltzmann Machines:

http://jarbm.sourceforge.net/

But I could neither get it's source code nor any detailed help about it's usage. They have java docs for this code but haven't explained about it's usage. No sample example is given.

There is a simple implementation I found in Python at:

https://github.com/echen/restricted-boltzmann-machines

Can anybody tell me where I can get similar implementation in java for both Boltzmann machines and Deep Learning?
(Best if I get with source code. Otherwise at least java library with sample usage code or detailed help on it's usage.)

Thanks,
Nitin

Comment: Have you looked at the Deeplearning4j implementation of restricted Boltzmann machines? https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j

Answer (score 3):

Did you try getting the source code for the jarbm project using cvs as described on this page: http://sourceforge.net/p/jarbm/code/?source=navbar ?